# Create a Custom Button that will popup a new email window

Tags: email, custom-button, case

I'm an administrator and I need a custom button in cases that will pop a new email window. I don't know how to do it.

I think that I will need some code here and I don`t know how to code. :(

Thanks for the help!

Comment: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000goIfAAI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible without any code. You will need to create the button on the case object with the `Content Source` set to `URL`.

Then you will want to use the following URL

`/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?rtype=003&p3_lkid={!Case.Id}&retURL=%2F{!Case.Id}&p5={!$User.Email}&p24="yourEmail@company.com&template_id=00XC0000001O7Ck`

Make sure that you populate your email address in the section `p24=""` and also replace the template id with the email template that you would like to use.

Please see this [post](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000goIfAAI) for some more information.